# Access 2010 update date in text box from a combobox

Tags: combobox, textbox, ms-access-2010

I have a combo box that has a status in it and when it is changed from Open to Closed, transferred or Pending I would like to populate two text boxes with the current date and time.  I have an after update module created that looks at the value of the combo box and then updates the text of the text box to the current date and time but it is not working.

It either doesn't do anything or I get an error about setting the focus.  I appreciate any help.

```
If Me.CmbStatus.Value = "Closed" Then 
    Me.Date_Completed.Text = Date 
    Me.Time_Completed.Text = Time 
ElseIf Me.CmbStatus.Value = "Pending" Then 
    Me.Date_Completed.Text = Date 
    Me.Time_Completed.Text = Time 
ElseIf Me.CmbStatus.Value = "Transferred" Then 
    Me.Date_Completed.Text = Date 
    Me.Time_Completed.Text = Time
```

Comment: Please edit your post by adding the relevant piece of code please.

Comment: If Me.CmbStatus.Value = "Closed" Then
     Me.Date_Completed.Text = Date
     Me.Time_Completed.Text = Time
ElseIf Me.CmbStatus.Value = "Pending" Then
     Me.Date_Completed.Text = Date
     Me.Time_Completed.Text = Time
ElseIf Me.CmbStatus.Value = "Transferred" Then
     Me.Date_Completed.Text = Date
     Me.Time_Completed.Text = Time

Comment: I did mention you to Edit your post. Please. This is an utter mess.

Comment: If the issue is with error 2185 (control needs the focus), then just delete the '.Text' part of your code.

Comment: I took out the .text and that did not work.  Thank you for the suggestion.  I did edit my post you asked for the relevant code, not sure what part of it is a mess.